# I can't install the react-to-pdf npm package

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, react-to-pdf

I have already tried this **"npm cache clean --force"**.

If you know another way of implementing a feature that allows users to download the webpage as a pdf, please let me know how.

This is the error I get when running **"npm install react-to-pdf"**:

`
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: cd-project@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.5.2" from react-to-pdf@0.0.14
npm ERR! node_modules/react-to-pdf
npm ERR!   react-to-pdf@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-03-02T18_55_48_074Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-03-02T18_55_48_074Z-debug-0.log
`

I tried this: `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: try  npm install react-to-pdf --legacy-peer-deps

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the version of React your project is using (`^18.2.0`) is not compatible with the `react-to-pdf` package's definition, which requires react version `^16.5.2` to be installed. At first glance, this may seem like an invalid error: the package expects a version higher than `16.5.2`, and you've installed something above `18.2.0`. However, any major version bump will create an incompatible state. We can understand this explicitly by reading [npm's documentation on this topic](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#peerdependencies), which states the following:

> Assuming the host complies with semver, only changes in the host package's major version will break your plugin. Thus, if you've worked with every 1.x version of the host package, use `"^1.0"` or `"1.x"` to express this. If you depend on features introduced in `1.5.2`, use `"^1.5.2"`.

Armed with all of that knowledge, we now have handful of options for resolving this issue:

1. Force install the plugin or use the `legacy peer dependencies` option, either of which provides no guarantee that this package works with your version of react.
2. Downgrade react (this is technically an option, but don't do it).
3. Find a more up-to-date alternative that accomplishes the same goal and is compatible with your version of react.

Additionally, if you really like this package, I would recommend opening up an issue on the maintainer's repository to ask for an update that tests compatibility with newer versions and publishes a new version of their own package.

Finally, I would recommend becoming familiar with this kind of error message and read through some of the official documentation on `npm`'s website because this kind of thing is fairly common and understanding the basics will save you many future headaches.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

- `npm install react-to-pdf --force`
- Choose a previous stable version, for example `npm install react-to-pdf@4.2.3`

Comment: I would suggest adding some comments as to _why_ these solutions may work and elaborate a bit more about what the root of the problem might be.